# Clean special character, numeric and character

Tags: r

I have a variable like below in my dataframe

```
df$emp_length(10+ years, <1 year, 8 years)
```

I need to clean this variable for better analysis. Example, I want to compare this variable with other categorical or numerical variable. What is the best way to seperate this variable in to multiple columns.

I am thinking to separate this variable based on space something like below,

```
df$emp_length = c(10+, <1, 8)     
df$years = c(years, years, years)
```

Also I would like to know if the number with special characters like + and < will be considered as numeric in R or I have to separate special character and numbers?

I want to have emp_length variable as numeric and years variable as character.

Please help!

Comment: What's value are you looking for `10+` and `<1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use `tidyr::extract` to first separate `emp_length` in 2 columns. Then replace any symbol (anything other than `0-9`) to `""` in column with number and then convert it to numeric.

**Option#1:** Keep the symbol with number

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% extract(emp_length, c("emp_length", "years"), 
                              regex="([[:digit:]+<]+)\\s+(\\w+)")

df
#   emp_length years
# 1        10+ years
# 2         <1  year
# 3          8 years
```

**Option#2:** Just number but column is numeric

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>% 
extract(emp_length, c("emp_length", "years"), regex="([[:digit:]+<]+)\\s+(\\w+)") %>%
  mutate(emp_length = as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]","\\1",emp_length)))

df
#   emp_length years
# 1         10 years
# 2          1  year
# 3          8 years
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(emp_length = c("10+ years", "<1 year", "8 years"),
                                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I dont want to create seperate column for special characters. The problem is that that data <1 year (starts with < symbol) has been changed to NA 1 instead of 1 and year. How to fix this?

Comment: I just noticed the space between less than < symbol and 1. The actual data is < 1 year. I think that is the problem. How to fix this?

Comment: You have to change your `regex` to handle it. In option#1 the solution can be as `df %>% extract(emp_length, c("emp_length", "years"), 
               regex="([[:digit:]+< ]+)\\s+(\\w+)$")`